# How to set encoding in gedit 3.2?

Tags: gedit

I can not display file coded with GBK.
In gconf-editor of gnome 3.2 , I can not find encoding item of gedit .
How to set it ? 
thanks

Comment: What is the output of `locale` and `locale -a`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't have a file encoded in GBK to test the solutions, but do try them.

**Option 1**: Run gedit and then open the file:

- run gedit
- click open
- select in the encoding combo "add" and add GB18030 (or GBK)
- select that encoding in the combo
- select the file

**Option 2**:

- install and run `gconf-editor`
- Find /apps/gedit-2/preferences/encoding key "auto_detected" and set it to:

  ```
  [CURRENT,GB18030,GBK,GB2312,UTF-8,UTF-16]
  ```

**Remember to backup the previous value of auto_detected!!**

**Option 3**:
Using dconf (the "newer" gconf, used in ubuntu)

```
dconf read /org/gnome/gedit/preferences/encodings/auto-detected
```

**Save the result (backup)!**

```
dconf write /org/gnome/gedit/preferences/encodings/auto-detected "['CURRENT', 'GBK', 'GB18030', 'GB2312', 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16']"
```

Sources:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/819714
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=576047#c2
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1456308
- http://forum.ubuntu-gr.org/viewtopic.php?p=221205&http#p221205

To reset it to default:
a) use the option you backed up from dconf read command

or b) try:

```
dconf reset /org/gnome/gedit/preferences/encodings/auto-detected
```

Comment: `Unexpected error: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input`

Answer (score 2):

If you want do it quick then install **medit**. All works from the box.

If you still want use **gedit** then you need do some work:

1. Set auto-detect

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.encodings auto-detected "['UTF-8', 'GBK', 'CURRENT', 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-16']"
   ```
2. Install plugin for manual choose encoding. Really useful, especially when **auto-detect** don't detect encoding properly

"Change encoding" plugin for gedit v3

```
# Download plugin
mkdir -p /tmp/encoding
cd /tmp/encoding
wget https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ge/gedit-encoding-plugin/gedit-encoding-plugin.tar.gz
tar -xzvf gedit-encoding-plugin.tar.gz

# Copy to plugins directory
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
cp /tmp/encoding/gedit-encoding-plugin/encoding.plugin /tmp/encoding/gedit-encoding-plugin/encodingpy.py ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins

# Remove /tmp/encoding
rm -Rf /tmp/encoding
```

Then run gedit. Choose **Edit**->**Preferences**->**Plugins**(tab)->Check "**Encoding**" checkbox. After you do that you can find "**Encoding**" in menu "**File**"

Plugin description:
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gedit-encoding-plugin/

Plugin for gedit v2. Same author as in plugin above:
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=108326 (this is .tgz ext, but be careful it is a tar only archive) 
or plugin for gedit v2 by another author:
http://petrstepanov.wordpress.com/2010/09/29/gedit-encoding-plugin/

!!! plugin for gedit v2 has got tar.gz ext, but it is only a tar archive that is not gzipped...

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.10 gconf-editor is removed. Use 'dconf-editor' as an instead.Or use command line tool 'dconf'.
And 'auto-detected' is replaced by 'candidate-encodings' :

```
dconf write /org/gnome/gedit/preferences/encodings/candidate-encodings "['CURRENT', 'GBK', 'GB18030', 'GB2312', 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16']"
```